# Swift - protocol method signature based on associatedtype

Tags: swift

Is it in Swift, like in TypeScript possible to define a struct where the methods depend on the generics?

```swift
protocol UseCase {
  associatedtype Request
  associatedtype Response
  func execute(controller: () throws -> Request) async throws -> Response
}
```

If `Request` is `Void`, the protocol should return a different method signature.

```swift
func execute() async throws -> Response
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write a protocol extension with `where Request == Void`:

```
extension UseCase where Request == Void {
    func execute() async throws -> Response {
        try await execute {}
    }
}
```

When `Request` is `Void`, you can still call `execute(controller:)`, but you can also call the parameterless `execute()`.

When you conform to the protocol, you would need to implement `execute(controller:)`, but this isn't a big problem, since you can just ignore the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your contract would be a lie, violating the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). You can get around it with an underscore and a default parameter, but I recommend against it.

Also, I think you want `Never`, not `Void`—[that's what Apple does](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/emptyview/body).

```swift
struct JuiceCase: UseCase {
  func execute(
    controller _: () throws -> Never = { fatalError() }
  ) async throws -> String {
    ""
  }
}
```

---

I'm trying to figure out what Cristik is saying in the comments but don't get it. What I see here is `JuiceCase` not semantically conforming to `UseCase`, even though it syntactically does. My interpretation of "substitutability" is that both must be correct—i.e. saying that `JuiceCase` *is* a `UseCase` is a lie, even though the compiler currently has no mechanism to verify that.

```swift
let juiceCase = JuiceCase()
try await juiceCase.execute() // ""
let useCase: some UseCase = juiceCase
try await useCase.execute { fatalError() } // ""
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245991/discussion-on-answer-by-jessy-swift-protocol-method-signature-based-on-associa).